# Select only default block-level elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery selector for all [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements?
Other than a naïeve list of the tags listed there.

To be clear: i *do not* want elements with CSS `display: block;`, like [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576564/how-to-select-first-block-level-parent-with-jquery) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456636/how-to-detect-if-html-contains-block-level-elements-using-jquery) provide.

Trivial but fragile/inelegant solution:

```
$('adress, article, aside, ..., tfoot, ul, video')
```

Solution using css `display`, which break if an element gets e.g. `display: none;`

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
})'
```

Comment: You don't have to define any, apart from html5 elements which you can declare in your CSS instead of doing that with jQuery

Comment: I could make a `<span>` block-level if I wanted to by just declaring it as such in a style sheet; do you want to cater for that, too?

Comment: This sounds like something you're doing *en route* to doing something you actually want to do. You might have more success if you ask about the actual thing you want to do. (I could be mistaken, of course, but I can't think of any reason to select elements that *would* be block elements if they weren't styled.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder valid point, altough I think it's the right solution here. I want to select all block-level siblings of an header until the next header: `$('h1,...,h6').nextUntil('h1,...,h6', blockLevelSelector)`. I have some generated html which I want to change+style and can't change the generator.

Comment: The question is, what does it matter if it's a block level element if someone specifically styled it as an inline element, why would you still need to return it as a block level element ?

Comment: The title is misleading in my humble opinion as [**by definition**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) the `display` property `block`, `list-item` and `table` make an element block-level.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Not if you use the [the HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) definition, although to be fair HTML5 doesn't define the term anymore, probably to prevent this confusion. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @adeneo Because I want to select all default block-level elements even if they have `display: none;` set, and don't want the default inline-level elements.

Comment: And to do that you have to either create a new element and get the computed style of that element or keep a list of elements that are known to be block level, and compare against the tagname of each element. This isn't rocket science, but you seem to not want to use any of the available solutions hoping for a magic pill, but there is none.

Comment: @adeneo Yes I understand. I do not know why you deleted your answer because I would have marked it as accepted, as it provides the requested selector. Even if in my personal opinion a simple list would be a better solution.

Comment: Nah, T.J is getting all the votes, just accept his answer instead.

Comment: @dtech: Ah yes, apologies I was looking at the CSS spec instead. Title makes sense then if in the context of the [**HTML spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3). Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no built-in CSS selector or jQuery extension that matches elements that are, by default, block-level.

You can select ones that are *currently* block-level based on the current style sheet and their specific style properties, but based on your comment about the `display` property (which would be an incomplete solution, btw, as it doesn't allow for style sheets), it doesn't sound like you want to do that.

The list doesn't change all that frequently, of course, so you *could* have a hardcoded list in your app. But it sounds like you don't want *that* either.

Comment: I guess having a list is good enough. Just wondering if there was a "better" solution.